# How can I print include path in cygwin?

Tags: cygwin

I am new to cygwin & I want to print the list of include paths cygwin will search for header files.

Is there a cygwin bash shell command to print the include path list?
if so, what it is ?
if there is n't any, how can I know the include path list cygwin will search for?

Answer (score 1):

echo $PATH (echo ${PATH}) would be one possibility. To show all environment variables type env.

Normally, include paths are defined by the Make-Environment, either in the makefile, along with the compiler call or within the cmake environment. This is better than to put it in the PATH environment because if someone compiles something different, the "old" include definition in the PATH environment variable maybe in the way (which is not, if you specify it for every project, e.g. in the Makefile or threw the cmake environment).

If someone still wants to define it in the PATH variable, it can be done on the command prompt (if your cygwin(64) resides on "cygdrive/c":

export PATH=/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/usr/include:$PATH